# What is "seed inference"?

Tags: anchor

Could someone provide an explanation and example of the "seed inference" feature?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a full example of how it works in the [`tests/pda-derivation`](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/tree/master/tests/pda-derivation) directory of the anchor repo.

If you use seeds that follow any of the below formats then the anchor client code can infer the correct address without additional inputs or needing to manually call `findProgramAddress`.

```
        seeds = [
            &seed_a.to_le_bytes(),
            "another-seed".as_bytes(),
            b"test".as_ref(),
            base.key().as_ref(),
            base2.key.as_ref(),
            MY_SEED.as_ref(),
            MY_SEED_STR.as_bytes(),
            MY_SEED_U8.to_le_bytes().as_ref(),
            &MY_SEED_U32.to_le_bytes(),
            &MY_SEED_U64.to_le_bytes(),
            base.base_data.to_le_bytes().as_ref(),
            base.base_data_key.as_ref(),
        ],
```

It's not a feature I use much though and it has a variety of restrictions. But that's the basic idea.